# CanActivate not called after updating to Angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I updated to angular 12 and on start it shows a white/blank page.

This is because I don't hit the canActivate method in my "RedirectGuard" which implements CanActivate, anymore. This should happen when path is empty.

My routing:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
{ 
  path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' 
},
{
  path: 'login',
  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
},
...
```

And my RedirectGuard:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authStateQuery: AuthenticationStateQuery
    ) {}
    
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      console.info('In RedirectGuard');
      
      if (this.authStateQuery.isLoggedIn()) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        return true;      
      }
      
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your routing doesn't mention the guard?

Comment: Did not change the code and it worked before so didn't even occurred to me something was missing. Don't know if it threw it away in the upgrade process. Anyway works like indented with "canActivate: [RedirectGuard]". Thank you @GaëlJ

Comment: @GaëlJ please create an answer, I can accept it then.

Answer (score 0):

Your `routes` definition doesn't include any reference to the guard.

Need something like following on the route:

```
canActivate: [RedirectGuard]
```